border is looking weard for my mat outlined fields in angular project
[screenshot](https://i.sstatic.net/YvQRcsx7.png)
my css is
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use "variables";
@include mat.core();

$axiom-primary: mat.define-palette(variables.$mat-color-palette);
$axiom-accent: mat.define-palette(variables.$mat-color-palette, A200, A100, A400);

$axiom-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$axiom-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
    color: (
        primary: $axiom-primary,
        accent: $axiom-accent,
        warn: $axiom-warn,
    ),
    typography: mat.define-typography-config(
        $font-family: inherit,
        //$subtitle-1: mat.define-typography-level($font-size: 1.2rem, $line-height: 1.2, $font-weight: 600),
        //$subtitle-2: mat.define-typography-level($font-size: 1rem, $line-height: 1.2, $font-weight: 600),
        //$body-1: mat.define-typography-level($font-size: 1rem),
        //$body-2: mat.define-typography-level($font-size: 1rem),
        $caption: mat.define-typography-level($font-size: 0.9rem),
        $button: mat.define-typography-level($font-size: 1rem),
    ),
    //density: 'minimum',
));

@include mat.select-typography(mat.define-typography-config(
    $font-family: inherit,
    $body-1: mat.define-typography-level($font-size: 1rem),
));
@include mat.form-field-typography(mat.define-typography-config(
    $font-family: inherit,
    $body-1: mat.define-typography-level($font-size: 1rem),
));
@include mat.form-field-density('minimum');

mat-form-field{
    --mat-mdc-form-field-floating-label-scale: 0.85 !important;

    .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper.mdc-text-field--outlined {
        .mat-mdc-form-field-flex .mat-mdc-floating-label {
            top: 50%;
        }
        .mdc-text-field__input {
            margin-top: .35rem;
        }
        .mdc-notched-outline--upgraded .mdc-floating-label--float-above{
            //translate: 0 3px;
        }
    }

    .mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled):not(.mdc-text-field--invalid):not(.mdc-text-field--focused) {
        .mdc-floating-label{
            color: #404040; // to change the label color.
        }
        .mdc-notched-outline__leading, .mdc-notched-outline__notch, .mdc-notched-outline__trailing{
            //border-color: red;
            //border-width: 2px;
        }
    }

    .mat-mdc-form-field-icon-suffix {
        .mat-icon {
            padding: 0 5px !important;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
        }
        .mat-mdc-icon-button{ // for date picker
            padding: 5px 5px;
            width: max-content;
            height: 100%;
        }
    }
}

my angular version is 15 and we are upgrading it form angular 8. can't understand what is the problem.
it is not coming at some zoom levels of browser. at some zoom levels it is more visible and at some zoom levels it is not at all visible.
i tried debugging from browser dev-tools but with no solution.
Thanks in advance.

I've had similar problem like this but a while ago, I'd try setting --mat-mdc-form-field-floating-label-scale to default and see what happens or removing the will-change: transform from .mdc-floating-label.
